# sharing my app link to other apps from my android app is not working

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, whatsapp

I have below code for android to share app with other applications like facebook, twitter, whatsapp ot watever.

It is opening the dialogue and showing the applications to choose anyone but when i choose the app it gives me the message **Sharing failed, please try later**

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("plain/text");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mWebView.getUrl());
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "share_with"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void shareApp(Context context) {
    final String appPackageName = context.getPackageName();
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Check this cool Sticker App at: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName);
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    context.startActivity(sendIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).setType("text/plain").putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mWebView.getUrl()));
```

or write **text/plain** in your code (2nd line)

Comment: it simply copy the url to text message i want to share with ther apps when i will click on button it should show the apps to choose one whatsapp viber imo or  whatever so i will choose the app suppose whatsapp and then user,

Comment: it is look like you are doing fine [you can refer this](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html#send-text-content)